# Intellij Gradle Disable Offline Mode

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, build.gradle

I got this error while trying to build the project. The error message shows the it is caused by the dependent file is not cached. I am wondering how to open download mode rather than offline. 
[image: I zz]

I did many searches, most suggestions are to edit the option on Gradle Setting in Android studio. However, the IntelliJ doesn't have this option...

[image]

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Gradle offline mode in IntelliJ IDEA and Android Studio can be toggled via the following toolbar icon in the Gradle tool window:

[image: Gradle | Toggle offline mode]

Comment: Is there a way for the offline mode to be toggled on by default , whenever a gradle-based project is newly imported into intellij.   Cos i do not want the intellij to immediately download the dependencies after importing a gradle-based project.