# Intellij Maven Detection Failing

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I'm having some issues correctly importing my maven project.
It has one main module containing 2 child modules. The parent's maven dependencies are not recognized in any of the children and many of the children's dependencies fail to resolve. The ones it does recognize do appear with the "Add to classpath" message and when adding nothing changes. This project works perfectly on my main device and all dependencies are resolved. Why am I running into this?

(Itis a private repo so unfortunately I am unable to share it)

Comment: Make sure to import the parent pom per https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/maven-support.html#maven_import_project_start. Check [idea.log](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241085) for errors. Check that Maven is [not in offline mode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58140634/104891).

Comment: Does it work as expected when running maven from the command line?